# .jumbotron background is covering the entire page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble figuring out why my jumbotron container is covering the entire page. I am trying to have the jumbotron stop right before "Find your university".

Second, I am also having trouble with moving the search bar to the middle of the jumbotron. Can anyone help? I'm new to HTML, CSS and Bootstrap.

HTML:

```
<div class="center jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>MOVE ABROAD WITH EASE</h1>

    <h2>Find out about the cities, where to live and eat, hangout groups.</h2>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="custom-search-input">
          <div class="input-group col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="  search-query form-control" placeholder="Which city are you moving to?" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
               <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
                 <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
               </button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
#custom-search-input {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 10;
}
```

[image]

Comment: you need to provide the css code, and a demo page please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `jumbotron` is likely filling your page because you have all your content inside of it. Just move everything from `Find Your University` and below out of it.

As for centering your input, Bootstrap provides the `col-xx-offset-#` concept to help with this.

[Here's a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e71o6oo9/4/) with your code updated to illustrate.

Some additional notes and pointers:

1. `padding: 10;` is invalid css (possibly just a typo). make sure to include `px` if that was your intention.
2. Creating your own `.center` class is unnecessary. Bootstrap comes with a `.text-center` class for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Drew!